# What is a practical way to model lookup tables in Domain Driven Design (DDD)?

Tags: domain-driven-design, lookup

I'm just learning DDD (Eric Evans book is open in front of me) and I've come across a problem that I can't find an answer for. What do you do in DDD when you're just trying to get a simple list of lookup records?

Ex.

EmployeeID: 123
EmployeeName: John Doe
State: Alaska (drop-down)
County: Wasilla (drop-down -- will be filtered based on state).

For example, let's say that you have an Employee domain object, an IEmployeeRepository interface and an EmployeeRepository class. This will be used by a UI to show a list of employees and individual details. In the UI, you want to use a drop-down for the State and County where the employee lives. The Available counties will be filtered based on which state was chosen.

Unfortunately, the database tables and the UI look very different. In tblEmployees, it contains State Code=AK and County Code=02130, not the State and County Names.

The old way (before I began this DDD quest) would be pretty straightforward, just create 2 queries and use a DataReader to populate the drop-downs. Underneath the display in the drop-downs is the value, which gets automatically used in form posts.

With DDD, though, I'm not sure how you're supposed to do this. I first started by creating State and County objects as well repositories and interfaces for the repositories. However, writing 4 classes + 2 interfaces and the plumbing in the hbm.xml files + Employee Business objects seems like overkill for just 2 queries for 2 drop-downs. There has to be a better way, doesn't there? I'm not changing the records in the State or County tables any time soon and even if I did, it wouldn't be through this application. So I don't really want to create business objects for State and County if I don't have to.

The simplest solution that I see is to just create a helper class with methods that return dictionaries, such as GetStatesAll(), GetState() and GetCounties() and GetCounty(), but that just feels wrong from a DDD perspective.

Please help. How can I use DDD without overengineering just a couple of simple lookups?

**Final Solution**
I think that I finally found my answer through experience, which was to put the GetStates() method into its own Data Access class, though not a repository class. Since I was only doing read-only access, I threw it into a struct DTO. Since the database was small, I threw them altogether into a single class, like Todd below described.

My conclusions:

1. Lookup tables are NEVER value objects, because lookup tables ALWAYS have an identity. If they didn't have an identity, you'd have duplicates, which wouldn't make much sense.

   Read-only lookup table can have a repository, but probably don't need one. The goal of a repository is to reduce complexity by forcing access only through the aggregate. Going through the aggregate provides you with a way to ensure that business rules can be enforced, such as not adding tires if you don't have a car.

   If you allow CRUD maintenance on the lookup table, then it makes sense for the lookup table to have its own repository.

   The fact that I ended up storing the codes as structs doesn't make them "value types". Fowler says in POEAA that a struct is a value type. That's true, structs are immutable, which is why Fowler says that they are "value types", however I was using them differently. I was using structs as a lightweight way to pass around DTOs that I didn't ever plan on changing after their initial creation. In truth, the structs that I used did, indeed, have identities, but since they were read-only they worked as structs.

   One pattern that I've been using that I don't see much elsewhere is to make primary key fields be immutable. They're set by the constructor, but they're read-only (not private accessors) and cannot be changed once the object is created.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? if yes ... please post it below ... thanks

Comment: Excellent wrap-up. This kind of follow-up is all-too-rare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to look into the concept of [Command Query Separation](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/12/ddd-command-query-separation-as-an-architectural-concept.aspx). I wouldn't worry about typed repositories for lookup values, but I'd still probably use DTO type classes over datasets etc...

You may want to spend some time reading Greg Young's blogs starting from [this one](http://codebetter.com/blogs/gregyoung/archive/2009/01/13/dddd-master-detail-question.aspx) to the present. He doesn't talk about filling lookup data specifically but he often talks about not handling the reading/reporting functionality of your application through typed methods on a repository.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that it's an exact answer, but it gets me on the right track which is "what's the best way to retrieve read-only data".

Answer (score 7):

Using DDD I have something similar with the following:

```
interface IAddressService
{
  IList<Country> GetCountries ();
  IList<State> GetStatesByCountry (string country);
  IList<City> GetCitiesByState (string state);
  // snip
}
```

Country, State and City are value objects which come from a lookup table in the database.

Comment: It would be a little better if parameters will be Country and State instead of string.

Answer (score 4):

Well I read an article by [Mathias Verraes](http://verraes.net/) some time ago talking about this [here](http://verraes.net/2013/11/value-objects-and-user-interfaces/). He talks about Separating value objects in the model from concepts that serve the UI.

Quoting from the article when asked whether to model Countries as entities or value object:

> There’s nothing intrinsically wrong with modelling countries as
>   entities and storing them in the database. But in most cases, that
>   overcomplicating things. Countries don’t change often. When a
>   country’s name changes, it is in fact, for all practical purposes, a
>   new country. If a country one day does not exist anymore, you can’t
>   simply change all addresses, because possibly the country was split
>   into two countries.

He suggested a different approach to introduce a new concept called `AvailableCountry`:

> These available countries can be entities in a database, records in a
>   JSON, or even simply a hardcoded list in your code. (That depends on
>   whether the business wants easy access to them through a UI.)

```
<?php

final class Country
{
    private $countryCode;

    public function __construct($countryCode)
    {
        $this->countryCode = $countryCode;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->countryCode;
    }
}

final class AvailableCountry
{
    private $country;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(Country $country, $name)
    {
        $this->country = $country;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /** @return Country */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

final class AvailableCountryRepository
{
    /** @return AvailableCountry[] */
    public function findAll()
    {
        return [
            'BE' => new AvailableCountry(new Country('BE'), 'Belgium'),
            'FR' => new AvailableCountry(new Country('FR'), 'France'),
            //...
        ];
    }

    /** @return AvailableCountry */
    public function findByCountry(Country $country)
    {
        return $this->findAll()[(string) $country];
    }
}
```

So it seems there is a 3rd solution which is to model look up tables as both value objects and entities.

BTW make sure u check the comments section for [some serious discussions](http://verraes.net/2013/11/value-objects-and-user-interfaces/#comment-1174666856) about the article.

Answer (score 3):

The state and county are not entities, but value objects. They are not the subject of your system. The way you said you treated these previously is OK. When will you change the state or county records in your database, based on the changes in the state of your domain model? Not, so these will not need a repository.

Comment: OK, That makes some sense. What threw me off somewhat was the fact that I am interested in the ID field of the objects, but that doesn't necessarily make them "entities", does it. 

Where do you put the creation of all the value objects go? Into a global ValueObjectFactory class? Is there a best practice?

Comment: I agree with @John: lookup tables like County and State are *not* value objects for one simple reason: they have ID, they're referenced by ID. The model could have an Address value object, which would have a reference to County and State. Just saying that to highlight the fact that VOs can reference entities.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading the wrong book if you want to learn how to do DDD without over complicating it. :-)

The simplest solution you're proposing is fine if it meets your needs. Encapsulating address data in business objects can be as simple or as complicated as your application demands. For example, the State object has a one-to-many relationship with County so Employee really just needs to reference a County if you chose to model it that way. I would only introduce that sort of complexity if required.

Additionally, I don't think there's much to be gained by defining interfaces for your repositories unless there's a real possibility that you might have multiple repositories for your objects.

Comment: My understanding is that you're not really doing DDD if you're not using interfaces for your repositories. And doesn't creating an interface for your repository more easily enable you to do mocks? Regardless, in Visual Studio it takes all of 1 second to generate an interface from a class you designed, so I don't really see a downside to using interface. Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of an interface if you only have one class that implements it? Concrete classes are just as mockable as interfaces. I do think that interfaces are valuable for services classes that may have more than one implementation and if you're using a dependency injection framework.

Comment: I would also argue that extracting an interface from a class is a backward approach -- the contract should be designed before the implementation. Done this way, interfaces do have an advantage for unit testing because tests can created using mocked interfaces before any concrete implementations are coded.

Comment: OK, it looks like I was mixing up Palermo's "Onion" framework, which does require interfaces for the repositories, with DDD. Also, every example that I come across so far showsg DDD repositories using interfaces, but that's probably a SOLID thing, not a DDD thing. 

Actually, what I do is create the class and stubs in Visual Studio's class designer, extract an interface and afterwards write the code. So I do agree -- interface before implementation. Thanks.

Comment: The point of having an interface for that only class is to be able to test it. You can then stub it, mock it ... eat it if you like ...
I agree with john ... you are doing well ... go ahead

Comment: "Concrete classes are just as mockable as interfaces."  That's not true.  You have to make properties virtual to mock them with Moq, at the very least, which I think obscures your intent.  I think you're better off putting interfaces as your constructor dependencies.  More SOLID.