# How do reference an Entity from a value object in Hibernate/NHibernate?

Tags: c#, java, hibernate, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

From the [DDD book by Eric Evans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215):

> VALUE OBJECTS can even reference ENTITIES. For example, if I ask an online map service for a scenic driving route from San Francisco to Los Angeles, it might derive a Route object linking L.A. and San Francisco via the Pacific Coast Highway. That Route object would be a VALUE, even though the three objects it references (two cities and a highway) are all ENTITIES.

[page #98](http://books.google.com/books?id=xColAAPGubgC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=For%20example,%20if%20I%20ask%20an%20online%20map%20service%20for%20a%20scenic%20driving%20route%20from%20San%20Francisco%20to%20Los%20Angeles&source=bl&ots=q9VzdhPL9o&sig=7dWT-cJyutWo52Ad-LRWYGRrmUI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NndOT5KKIIjJiQLJvZyOCw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=For%20example,%20if%20I%20ask%20an%20online%20map%20service%20for%20a%20scenic%20driving%20route%20from%20San%20Francisco%20to%20Los%20Angeles&f=false)

In Hibernate if I have a value object I can map it with as a component. What if I want to reference an entity form that component?

Example:

- I have a Users table.
- Each User can have many addresses.
- I create a addresses table, but I treat the addresses as value objects in my domain.
- Each address have a type (work address, home address,...etc.)
- I create a address type table as a look up and treat it as an entity in my domain.
- An address should have a reference to it type.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Declare an one-to-one relationship in the componnent?

Comment: Why is address type an entity? Do you care about its identity?

Comment: @JefClaes I was influenced by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/808481/636342) on SO. Do you think it's better modeled as a VO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-component).

> The `<component>` element maps properties of a child object to columns of the table of a parent class. Components may, in turn, declare their own properties, components or collections. See "Components" below.
>
> ```
> <component>                 <!-- NOTE: I'm omitting the attributes. See docs for details on these. -->
>        <property ...../>
>        <many-to-one .... />
>        ........
> </component>
> ```

Notice the example `property` and `many-to-one` in the code above.  To create a reference to another entity, you simply use `many-to-one` inside the component, just as you would outside the component.